# ConTeXt: How do I have a box of 2-column text in a layer?

Tags: context, layers

In my MWE, below, I want to have a frame, starting at the left margin, containing 2 columns of text. Instead, it has a column of the right width, but the text does not flow into the second column as I hoped.

My questions are:

1 - I've put the text into the layer as a frame, because I can specify the height and width of the frame. I don't actually need a frame drawn around the text. Is a frame the best way to put a box of text into a layer, or are there other ways?

2 - How can I make the text in the frame be in 2 columns?

3 - Why is the text moved down from the top of the frame? If I remove the `\startcolumns[n=2]` and `\stopcolumns` in the MWE the text isn't moved down.

```
\showframe %\showgrid
\setuplayout[backspace=80mm, width=100mm, topspace=50mm, header=0mm, footer=0mm, height=200mm, margindistance=10mm, leftmargin=40mm]

\definelayer[new]   
[x=0mm, y=0mm,  width=160mm, height=200mm]

\setlayer[new]  
[hoffset=30mm, voffset=150mm] 
{\framed[frame=on, location=middle,align=flushleft,width=120mm, height=30mm]{\startcolumns[n=2]So, l recently bought a small clock. I didn’t need a clock, but it was there, and l could, so l did. It’s just as well l didn’t need it, because although it has a face showing hours, and another one for minutes, both are quite hard to read.\stopcolumns} } 

\starttext  
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=new]
\dorecurse{1}{\input{knuth} }
\stoptext
```

[image: MWEFails]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing two things:

1. `\startcolumns ... \stopcolumns` is an *outer* macro meant to be used at the page level. If you want columns inside a frame, use `\startsimplecolumns .. \stopsimplecolumns`.
2. `\setlayer[...]{...}` should be used *after* the font setup. In your example, you do not have any font setup, so ConTeXt loads the default font setup at `\starttext`. So, when you call `\setlayer[...]`, no font has been set and that is the reason you get the output in teletype font. This can be avoided by either adding an explicit font setup, or moving `\setlayer[...]` after `\starttext`.

Comment: Great. Just changing from columns to simplecolumns didn't do much, but moving `\setlayer[…]` to after `\starttext` fixed everything. I imagine `\starttext` loads other necessary things too.